Display a button when making a list of buttons for category from table database
I wrote the code correctly but I don't know what the problem is.
Code:
    private void AddCategory()
    {
        string qry = "select * from category";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qry, MainClass.con);

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);

        categoryPanel.Controls.Clear();

        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                //Button b = new Button();
                Guna.UI.WinForms.GunaButton b = new Guna.UI.WinForms.GunaButton();
                b.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(50, 55, 89);
                b.Size = new Size(134, 45);
                //b.ButtonMode = Guna.UI.WinForms.Enums.ButtonMode.RadioButton;
                //  b. = Guna.UI.WinForms.GunaRadioButton;
                b.Text = row["catName"].ToString();
                categoryPanel.Controls.Add(b);   
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Label lbl = new Label();
            lbl.Text = "No Category Found!";
            categoryPanel.Controls.Add(lbl);
        }
    }

Database :

Result :

I want the result to be all category as buttons

Have you debugged your code? Is the loop executed? What control is categoryPanel? Most container controls will need to position controls on it by setting its Location.

Sidenotes. Don't reuse the SqlConnection just create a new one. Handle disposing things correctly most SqlXXX classes are Disposable.

yes I debugged with no error ! no control on categoryPanel  @Ralf

Let's start at the beginning. Are you sure that you're sending your query to the database? Is your connection open?

Yes, the connection open to monitor that the results appear in the first raw only , that mean connection open

All the buttons have the same location (stacked on top of each other)

I changed tool from (Panel) to (FlowLayoutPanel)

Based on my test, I reproduced your problem that I only could generate one button from database table.
I find that you did not give the Location property, so you met the problem.
Please use the following code to modify it.
 int i = 0;
 if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
 {
     foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
     {
         Button b = new Button();
         //Guna.UI.WinForms.GunaButton b = new Guna.UI.WinForms.GunaButton();
         b.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(50, 55, 89);
         b.Size = new Size(134, 45);
         b.Location = new Point(100, 100 + 80 * i);
         //b.ButtonMode = Guna.UI.WinForms.Enums.ButtonMode.RadioButton;
         //  b. = Guna.UI.WinForms.GunaRadioButton;
         b.Text = row["Name"].ToString();
         panel1.Controls.Add(b);
         i++;
     }
 }
 else
 {
     Label lbl = new Label();
     lbl.Text = "No Category Found!";
     panel1.Controls.Add(lbl);
 }

You could see the following result:

